# Why's PHP complaining about my register_shutdown_function()?

Tags: php

I try to register a shutdown function to log an fatal error. Nice stuff, if it would work for my class...

Inside a method I do this:

```
register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'handleFatalError'));
```

handleFatalError is not static, and it's public:

```
public function handleFatalErrors() {
    if(is_null($e = error_get_last()) === false) {
        //mail('your.email@example.com', 'Error from auto_prepend', print_r($e, true));
    }
}
```

PHP says:

> Warning: register_shutdown_function()
>   [function.register-shutdown-function]:
>   Invalid shutdown callback
>   'ErrorManager::handleFatalError'
>   passed in  ...

Why's that an invalid callback?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you're attempting to register 'handleFatalError' and the method is called 'handleFatalErrors'.

Er... that's it really.

Comment: you're right man. %$§!!!

Comment: @middaparka Even I'm getting this error. But I haven't made any typo errors. What else could be the possibility for this to occur?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it should be:

```
register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'handleFatalErrors'));
```

Note the s on `handleFatalErrors`

Answer (score 0):

The shutdown function is probably called after all objects have been deconstructed, have you tried:

```
register_shutdown_function(array('ErrorManager', 'handleFatalError'));
```

Comment: I had a ugly typo in my code. Damn.